# unittest error while working with BOTO3 WaiterError

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, boto3

I am using unittest framework to write test case and executing the test cases using Pytest. I want to use the unittest assertXXX() statements because I like the syntax of unittest.

My test case need to confirm that function being tested raises `WaiterError` from BotoCore Errors.

```
from unittest import TestCase as tc
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError, WaiterError


def test_verify_multipart_file_fail_wrong_key():
    '''
    Effect would be same for both wrong key or bucket name or the combination of these two.
    '''
    expected_eTag = 'ea7528d0be3572e7cfeefe1cb4a77ac8-3"'
    bucket_name = "bckt-entertainment-master"
    key = "wrong_key_cantexist_765443099877665544_not_AT_aLl.txt"
    s3_client, s3_resource = get_s3()
    
    # does not work
    # tc().assertRaises( WaiterError
    #        , verify_multipart_uploaded_fl(s3_client, s3_resource, expected_eTag, bucket_name, key))
        
    # works
    tc().assertRaises( WaiterError
             , verify_multipart_uploaded_fl,s3_client, s3_resource, expected_eTag, bucket_name, key)
```

However the **same syntax as the does not work block works** in another test case as shown below.

```
# works in another test case
tc().assertTrue(verify_multipart_uploaded_fl(s3_client, s3_resource, expected_eTag, bucket_name, key))
```

Why is this? Can anyone explain? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use `pytest.raises`? And if you want to use `unittest` syntax, why not derive from `unittest.TestCase`?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I am using `pytest.raises` that is working as expected ... I am not deriving from `unittest.TestCase` because I am not a big proponent of using Classes if not needed ... I use this form because I like the Unittest syntax of the assertXXX() ...

Comment: Your syntax for `assertRaises` won't work, because you call the function you test before it is added as a parameter to `assertRaises`.  If you want to write out the function call, you have to use the context manager version, e.g. `with tc().assertRaises(...):` or `with pytest.raises(...):`.